# pandas: apply a function to each unique element in a dataframe column and merge back the output

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider a data frame:

```py
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.random(size=10)})
df["y"] = np.where(df.x < 0.5, 0, 1)
```

Output:

```
          x  y
0  0.696469  1
1  0.286139  0
2  0.226851  0
3  0.551315  1
4  0.719469  1
5  0.423106  0
6  0.980764  1
7  0.684830  1
8  0.480932  0
9  0.392118  0
```

I would like to add a new column called `id`:

```
          x  y    id
0  0.696469  1  id_1
1  0.286139  0  id_0
2  0.226851  0  id_0
3  0.551315  1  id_1
4  0.719469  1  id_1
5  0.423106  0  id_0
6  0.980764  1  id_1
7  0.684830  1  id_1
8  0.480932  0  id_0
9  0.392118  0  id_0
```

I figured out that I can use `apply` function

```py
df.groupby("y").apply(lambda d: "id_%d" % d.name)
```

Output:

```
0    id_0
1    id_1
dtype: object
```

**Q1:** How can I merge the output of `apply` function back to the original data frame?

**Q2:** Is there a more elegant way to add `id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a column with:

```
df['id'] = df['y'].apply(lambda d: "id_%d" % d)
```

this returns:

```
          x  y    id
0  0.696469  1  id_1
1  0.286139  0  id_0
2  0.226851  0  id_0
3  0.551315  1  id_1
4  0.719469  1  id_1
5  0.423106  0  id_0
6  0.980764  1  id_1
7  0.684830  1  id_1
8  0.480932  0  id_0
9  0.392118  0  id_0
```

EDIT:
If you need to use your:

```
func = df.groupby("y").apply(lambda d: "id_%d" % d.name)
```

you can later use `map`:

```
df['id'] = df['y'].map(func)
```

Comment: Do you know a more efficient way? With your solution I have to call lambda-function "number of rows" times, and with `df.groupby("y").apply(lambda d: "id_%d" % d.name)` I have to call it only with "number of groups" times. In my real example calling lambda function is costly, so with your solution it takes quite a long time to compute...

Comment: Thank you! And what if my lambda function returns an array of the same size as the number of rows in each group? It doesn't work with the same trick..

Comment: @Denis consider posting another question updating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This approach isolates the unique values, applies the function to these unique values, and then merges them into the parent dataframe. It effectively replaces the original column.

```py
import pandas as pd

# DEFINE INPUTS:
df = pd.read_csv("https://j." + "mp/iriscsv")
mycol = "species"
myfunction = lambda v: print(f"Applying once to {v}") or v.title()

# APPLY TO UNIQUE VALUES ONLY, AND CREATE MAPPING:
mycol_unique = df[mycol].drop_duplicates()
mycol_unique_new = mycol_unique.apply(myfunction)
df_map = pd.concat([mycol_unique, mycol_unique_new], axis="columns")
mycol_new = f"{mycol}_new"
df_map.columns = [mycol, mycol_new]
del mycol_unique, mycol_unique_new

# MERGE:
assert mycol_new not in df.columns
df[mycol] = df[[mycol]].merge(df_map, how="left", on=mycol, validate="m:1").set_index(mycol.index)[mycol_new]
del df_map
```

Quite importantly, note the use of `.set_index(mycol.index)` above, without which the results are incorrect. It is necessary because `df.merge` resets the index of the returned dataframe.

Note: `validate="m:1"` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You use the column directly without `apply()`:

```
>>> df['id'] = 'id_' + df.y.astype(str)
>>> df

          x  y    id
0  0.696469  1  id_1
1  0.286139  0  id_0
2  0.226851  0  id_0
3  0.551315  1  id_1
4  0.719469  1  id_1
5  0.423106  0  id_0
6  0.980764  1  id_1
7  0.684830  1  id_1
8  0.480932  0  id_0
9  0.392118  0  id_0
```

Comment: Good hack, but in my real example when I call lambda function I request some metadata from a database, so your solution is not generic enough... :)